# The exclude-mapping of interceptor is not working in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, web, interceptor

I want to make an interceptor that will intercept every request except that related to login. The problem that I have is the interceptor still intercepts the requests that I provided with exclude-mapping. But the exclude-mapping is not working.
Here is the configuration,spring 4.3:

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <beans:bean class="com.knowledge.filter.GlobalInterceptor" />
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/back" />
        <mvc:exclude-mapping path="/back/login" />
        <beans:bean class="com.knowledge.filter.LoginInterceptor" />
    </mvc:interceptor>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

In my opinion, the "/back/login" should not be intercepted. Actually still get into the class of the interceptor.So, do i make some mistakes?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend writing separate mapping for every individual path instead of grouping it until and unless you have common implementation for all the services. Excluding will be possible if login and back are separate rest controllers, Not one being child of other.

You can refer this example for spring 4.

http://www.kscodes.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-interceptor-example/